# What is the purpose of the Windows registry key "Epoch"

Tags: windows-7, python, windows-registry, pycharm

Out of curiosity, what is the purpose of the registry key `Epoch`:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\SharedAccess\Epoch
```

[image]

My security software is warning me about the creation of this entry when running Python code (from IDE PyCharm) to open a file using Qt class [QFileDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame, QMainWindow, QWidget, QFileDialog


class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.show()
        dialog = QFileDialog(self, "Open File")
        dialog.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog.AcceptOpen)
        dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.ExistingFile)
        dialog.exec_()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    _ = Window()
    status = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(status)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Process Monitor trace:

[image]

Comment: Is your Python code from a trusted source? Rootkits can cause this.

Comment: "My security software is warning me" - What is the warning?  Please edit your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Epoch` key represents the timestamp that the value was changed. The values within the `SharedAccess` key represent Windows Firewall preferences. This is why the specific keys are being flagged by your antivirus software.

Comment: Thanks, so this key tells about when *another* change was done. Can we know which one?

Comment: @mins Unfortunately, no. It's used as part of the automatic refresh of firewall options within the GUI and provides no other detail.